# A basic question about compact $C^1$ surfaces with boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a compact and locally $C^1$  simply-connected surface with a $C^1$ boundary with no self intersection. Is there a $C^1$ bijection $F: \overline{B(0,1)} \rightarrow \overline{S}$ such that $ a|\xi|^2 \leq (D F)_{i,j} \xi_i \xi_j \leq A |\xi|^2$ (a,A>0), $F$ maps $\partial B(0,1)$ to $\partial S$, and $F^{-1}$ is also a $C^1$ map? How such a map could be reconstructed? I would appreciate a reference.

Basically, I am looking for a nice differentiable map between $S$ and $B(0,1)$.

Comment: Is $S$ a hypersurface in Euclidean space?

Comment: What is $S$ is an annulus, not $C^1$ diffeomorphic to a closed ball?

Comment: When you ask about constructing such a map, what data do you provide? For example, do you know $S$ as a Riemannian manifold, with an explicit metric, and then I have to find $F$?

Comment: Your question is rather vague, and appears to be using terminology different than what people use in differential topology/geometry.  Generally co-dimension one submanifolds are not discs or balls, if that's what your question is concerned with.

Comment: @BenMcKay Yes, you are right. Assume that $S$ is diffeomorphic to a closed ball.

Comment: @RyanBudney I added the assumption that $S$ is simply connected co-dimension 1 surface.

Comment: So you are asking that there is a diffeomorphism between the surface and a ball, together with what looks like some control on the norm of the derivative?  If that's what you want, yes, it follows from compactness.

Comment: @RyanBudney Compactness and probably partition of unity?

Comment: Partitions of unity come for free unless you are using some non-standard definition of a surface.

Comment: @RyanBudney Thank you Ryan, but I still can't figure out how to construct such map? Could you please elaborate a little more on this?

Comment: You have assumed the existence of a $C^1$ diffeomorphism between a closed ball and your submanifold. Hence they are homeomorphic, so both are compact. Every $C^1$ map between manifolds has $C^0$ bound locally on its differential.  By compactness, this local bound gives a globally bounded differential.

Comment: @BenMcKay We have only assumed assumed that locally there is a C^1 map between the manifold and closed ball. My problem is how to make this map a global map. Getting a bound after seems straightforward. Thanks.

Comment: @MathLearner: if you don't assume that there is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism between the manifold and a closed ball, what do you assume? Every $C^1$ manifold is locally $C^1$ diffeomorphic to a ball, so the annulus is a counterexample to existence of a global $C^1$ diffeomorphism. Can you perhaps rewrite the question to make your hypotheses precise?

Comment: @BenMcKay I have done that. We assume the surface is simply-connected.

Comment: Is the surface $S$ compact?

Comment: @BenMcKay Yes, I just added this assumption too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the classification of surfaces, $S$ is $C^1$ diffeomorphic to a closed disk (Morris Hirsch, Differential Topology, p. 205 theorem 3.7, for the $C^{\infty}$ case, combined with Whitney's smoothing theorem [p. 51 theorem 2.9] to get from $C^{\infty}$ to $C^1$). But any $C^1$ diffeomorphism $F \colon B \to S$ from the closed disk has locally bounded differential, in any Riemannian metric (because it is $C^1$), and so by compactness that bound has a maximum.